# SQL Function Parameter default as select

Tags: sql, function, parameters, azure-sql-database, parameter-passing

Function `A`, scalar, returns smallint (a year)
Function `B`, scalar, returns smallint (a month)
Function `C`, table, displays users based on year and month.

They work fine.

I would like to set default parameter of Function `C` to come from Func `A` & `B` like:

```sql
@year smallint = SELECT FunctA(), @month smallint = SELECT FunctB()
```

Is there anyway around this?

We are on Azure SQL Managed Instance.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Azure SQL. I added to above

Comment: I added the [tag:azure-sql-database] tag. In the future, tagging your question accurately helps you because it attracts the attention of the people most able to give you good answers.

Comment: Don't use scalars unless you're on SQL2019

Answer (score 1):

On thing you could use is something like

```
IF @year IS NULL
BEGIN
  SET @year = functa();
END;

IF @month IS NULL
BEGIN
  SET @month = functb();
END;
```

(or whatever the analog syntax is in the DBMS you didn't disclose).
 And when you want the defaults, pass `NULL`s as parameters.

Comment: Tried that. Not allowed in table function. Unless I am putting the 'IF' in the wrong place

Comment: @Amommy It is allowed in a multistep table-valued function. It is not allowed in an inline table-valued function. If you have an inline table-valued function, you can use `isnull(@year, functa())` everywhere where `@year` is expected, but that is likely to kill performance. You can play with various ways to work around that, such as `outer apply (select isnull(@year, functa())) as actual_value(year)`, but it is not guaranteed to perform better.